# Como pegar o Id da tabela do mysql por uma combobox

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, delphi-xe6

Minha dúvida é tenho uma combobox na aplicação e essa combobox é preenchida com dados vindo do banco mysql até ai tudo bem. Eu lanço os dados em um DataSource pra alimentar a combobox porém quando o usuário escolhe um resultado da combobox como por exemplo: Setor = FINANCEIRO eu quero gravar no banco o Id do setor financeiro e não a palavra financeiro. Como posso pegar esse Id?

`ParamByName('SETOR').AsString := SETOR.????????;`  ==> Aqui é onde fica minha combobox chamada de setor.

Comment: Informe como os dados da combo são carregados, pois isso influencia no retorno dos dados.

Comment: Tenho um TMyquery que faço um select assim:

with Query_Setor do
     begin
      Close;
      SQL.Clear;
      SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tabelas_sistema_setor WHERE STATUS = ''A''');
      Open;

      while NOT Query_Setor.Eof do begin
      SETOR.Items.Add(Query_Setor['SETOR']);
      Query_Setor.Next;
      end;
     end;

Depois tenho um:  TMyDataSource que alimenta essa combobox.

Answer (score 1):

O que pretendes é o comportamento da *TDBLookupComboBox*. Esta permite que ligues a um *datasource* e que definas o campo que o utilizador vê (ListField) e aquele que tu vais usar (KeyField).

Mas no teu caso se calhar nao precisavas de uma TDBLookupComboBox mas sim de uma TLookupComboBox, que tanto quanto sei só com componentes externos (pessoalmente uso os da DevExpress)